# How does the built-in Object constructor function look like behind the scene?

Tags: javascript

During my investigation, I discovered that a newly instantiated object, even if it is still empty, has access to properties and methods via the dot operator. I later discovered that these properties and methods are derived from the built-in Object constructor function, which is invoked when a new object is created. I'm now curious to learn more about this Object constructor function, specifically what properties and methods it has. I've been surfing the web for about a week and all I've learned is how to write my own constructor function, but what I really want to see is how the built-in Object constructor appears with its contents. The following is how I attempted to come up with a basic sketch of what I want to know on my own.

```
const Object = function () {
  // property of Object
  this.prototype = {
    constructor: Object,
    propertyIsEnumerable: function () {},
    toLocaleString: function () {},
    toString: function () {},
    valueOf: function () {},
    values: function () {},
  };
  // methods of Object
  this.create = function () {};
  this.defineProperties = function () {};
  this.defineProperty = function () {};
  this.entries = function () {};
  this.freeze = function () {};
  this.fromEntries = function () {};
  this.getOwnPropertyDescriptor = function () {};
  this.getOwnPropertyDescriptors = function () {};
  this.getOwnPropertyNames = function () {};
  this.getOwnPropertySymbols = function () {};
  this.getPrototypeOf = function () {};
  this.is = function () {};
  this.isExtensible = function () {};
  this.isFrozen = function () {};
  this.isSealed = function () {};
  this.keys = function () {};
  this.preventExtensions = function () {};
  this.seal = function () {};
  this.setPrototypeOf = function () {};
  this.values = function () {};
};
```

Comment: Every "plain" objects as `Object.prototype` as their _prototype_. That's where those methods are defined. I think you want to learn about prototypes rather than the `Object` function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Comment: You are right Felix Kling, learning about prototypes was all I wanted.